# Ctrl + G doesn't return the control back to the VM in VMplayer

Tags: vmware-player

I'm running an Ubuntu VM on VMplayer 12 over Windows 7, with the flag `pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar` turned on.

If I'm pressing Ctrl+Alt, the control is passed successfully from the VM to windows, but pressing Ctrl+G doesn't return the control back to the VM like it should (I remember using it in the past).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to assign a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: I would check two things: first, that the VMplayer window is focused when you press CTRL+G, and then that there are no other running apps that intercept this key combination; I'm thinking utilities that sit in the tray and register some hotkeys.

Comment: The window is focused (I guess), since it happens even immediately after removing control by Ctrl+Alt. And, as far as I know of, no other programs with Ctrl+G shortcut (it doesn't do anything)

Comment: Well, it does not need to do anything visible. I added the line `pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar = "TRUE"` to my `preferences.ini` and CTRL+G continues to work as expected, so the issue you describe does not seems to not depend on this setting.

Comment: I just mentioned that, I didn't say this is the issue

Comment: Of course. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. I assume it is persistent across host reboots and different VMs. Are there any other modifications to `preferences.ini`? I would try with a different user on the same host.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, it seems `pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar` is causing the issue somehow. For me, the only way to get Ctrl+G working again is to remove the flag (and I've had this issue on several machines).

If you just want to hide the toolbar without disabling it instead, you may add `pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.autohideSize = "0"` to your `preferences.ini` file. While the toolbar will still appear when you move the cursor to the top of the screen, it will be fully hidden otherwise and Ctrl+G and everything else will work as expected.